# React Router error: no routes matched location "/#about" for my about page. (Vite+ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

I tried to implement React Router Dom to route my About.jsx but my console gave me an error <--no routes matched location "/#about"-->
I installed react-router-dom with npm and imported it, here I only kept the necessary components related to my error.

```
//My App.jsx:

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import About from "./About";
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; 

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

//My About.jsx:

import React from "react";

function About() {
  return (
    <>
      <section id="about">
        <div className="container">
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis
            explicabo, voluptates adipisci porro asperiores nesciunt optio
            consequatur minima facere debitis voluptas inventore unde
            repellendus repellat sed vitae ex! Excepturi, magni?
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default About;
```

I want to get React router to implement my about page when I click on it.

Comment: just try giving path prop to `<Routes>` whose value should be basepath in your case "/"

Answer (score 1):

From your error it looks like you have the "#" sign in the "/#about" path, but your route path is "/about".

Comment: Yes, it worked, but I used # in the navbar so that if I click on it the site would scroll to that section... Also, when I open the about section it should be the only component with navbar on the page, how do I do it?

Comment: I just pushed the changes to GitHub, I've hosted it on netlify but it gives an err page not found... when I click on about https://mjshubham21.live/ <- my site.

Comment: it's a work in progress, I just started this site, and it's not yet responsive.

Comment: @mjshubham21 with the correct route path ("/about"), it will navigate and show what is on the about component alone. Just like what you've done on your "contact page". Or you change your route path in your app component to ("/#about")

Comment: didn't work as expected, as I click on about me (I added _blank to it) it opens on a new tab but along with all other components in the local host, and the same error page was not found on the live site!!!! https://mjshubham21.live/ About.jsx is a component do I have to make a new about.html to make it work??